# Camel SpringBoot POST returning Object NOT JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am completely new to Camel, I have created two simple REST end points(using Camel 3.8.0 and SpringBoot 2.4.3), one GET and one POST, like this -

```java
@Component
public class CamelController extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        restConfiguration()
                .component("servlet")
                .port(8080)
                .host("127.0.0.1")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

        rest().post("/order")
                .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .type(Order.class)
                .outType(Order.class)
                .to("bean:orderService?method=addOrder(${body})");

        rest().get("/order")
                .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .to("bean:orderService?method=getOrders()");

    }
}
```

When I call GET on http://localhost:8080/order I am getting an array of JSON(as expected), like this -

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Pencil",
    "price": 100.0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Pen",
    "price": 300.0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Book",
    "price": 350.0
  }
]
```

**But, when I make a POST request on http://localhost:8080/order with input**

```json
{
    "name": "A4 Papers",
    "price": 55.5
}
```

**Then it is returning Object**, like -

Order(id=6, name=A4 Papers, price=55.5)

**How can I make it to return JSON?**
Like -

```json
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "A4 Papers",
    "price": 55.5
}
```

My pom.xml

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>

    <camelVersion>3.8.0</camelVersion>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- SpringBoot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Camel -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${camelVersion}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${camelVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camelVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camelVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Others -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.18</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My complete code is he - https://github.com/crsardar/hands-on-java/tree/master/hands-on-camel-springboot

**How can I make the POST API to return JSON?**

Answer (score 0):

Your output data is a As you are using `outType`, your data which is an object of type Order is getting mapped into an arraylist. You need to convert your data explicitly into json format.

```
rest()
  .post("/order")
  .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  .type(Order.class)
  .route()
    .to("bean:orderService?method=addOrder(${body})")
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson);
```

Comment: This will give an out like - 

"W3siaWQiOjEsIm5hbWUiOiJQZW5jaWwiLCJwcmljZSI6MTAwLjB9LHsiaWQiOjIsIm5hbWUiOiJQZW4iLCJwcmljZSI6MzAwLjB9LHsiaWQiOjMsIm5hbWUiOiJCb29rIiwicHJpY2UiOjM1MC4wfSx7ImlkIjo1LCJuYW1lIjoiQTQgUGFwZXJzIiwicHJpY2UiOjU1LjV9XQ=="

Comment: this is a base64 encoding of the json output. Remove the .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json) from your restConfiguration

Comment: If we remove  " .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json) "

we will get 
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache to the required type: com.crsardar.java.dao.Order with value org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@76aca0ca
 at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:275)
 at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$ParameterExpression.evaluateParameterValue(MethodInfo.java:713)
 ... 53 more

Answer (score 0):

Add marshaling before hitting API.

```
rest().post("/order")
.produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Order.class)
.to("bean:orderService?method=addOrder(${body})");
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. The code mentioned by you, having compilation error.

My complete code is he - https://github.com/crsardar/hands-on-java/tree/master/hands-on-camel-springboot

please pull and check

Comment: did u override any tostring method in order class ? seems working for me @CRSardar

Comment: No buddy, It is as in the repo, I am changing only in "public class CamelController extends RouteBuilder" as you mentioned.

Do you have GitHub repository? Can you please share your codes in GutHub?

Comment: https://github.com/karthick-mr/camel-test/edit/master/README.md.. for me camel version was throwing error.. so used a different version.. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I pulled your project on the referenced Github url:  https://github.com/crsardar/hands-on-java/tree/master/hands-on-camel-springboot and found that it throws an error at compilation time due to the `camel-servlet-starter`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
   <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

I then proceeded to update it to use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
   <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Once I imported this dependency I was able to get the project running, and I tested the `POST` endpoint `http://localhost:8080/camel/order` and was getting the expected output

[image]

resulting in me not doing any code changes and yet getting the result you wanted, also one thing I've noticed in your yml file you use the `/camel` as your `context-path` yet in your above question you don't use in your rest call, leading me to believe that there is a project version mismatch.

Based on your question and the Github project you referenced above and also the investigation I did, hope this assists.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I you are correct. I have fixed this in latest version of it. Thanks. But, in any version, on my system, there it was always working fine, without any error. Whatever, Thank you so much.